# How to analyze temporal data in regression

Tags: r, regression, time-series, dataset

I have monthly temperature averages for a weather station across 100 years.
I am wondering how I should analyze this data in a regression.

The data are set up in the following fashion:

```
year  month  temp.avg
1900    11      9 
1900    12      6       
1901    01      5 
1901    02      4 
....
2015    12      7
```

My question is: **how do I go about accounting for the time and incorporating it into my model?**

Here are my **4 proposed methods:**

1. Should I add a "time" variable which essentially counts my months from 1 through *n* rows of data?

   - Ex: Using the example above, I would have a "time" column of 1,2,3,4,etc.
   - I essentially lose the actual year & month data, but does this matter? -- can I just add back, for example, "Dec 1900" for time 1?
2. Given a month *i* in year *j*, should I create a continuous time by adding 0.0833 (1/12) to each year for each i-1 month?

   - Ex. Again using the above example, I would have a "time" column consisting of values 1900, 1900.8333, 1900.9167, 1901.0000, 1901.0833, etc...
   - The linear regression model for the prior two methods would essentially be: `lm(temp.avg ~ time)`
3. Do I just incorporate year and month (or perhaps more usefully *season*) in the model together?

   - This would result in: `lm(temp.avg ~ year + month)`
4. Or is 3 wrong and instead I'd have to create a dummy variable for each month (or season)?

   - `lm(temp.avg ~ year + jan + feb + mar + apr ...)`

So **which is correct?** 
I assume perhaps the questions I'm asking would dictate this to some degree. But perhaps someone could describe simply the validity of each method and when to apply each?

Note: I understand that I will have to account for temporal autocorrelation, but I'm wondering how I incorporate time data *prior* to worrying about that.

I will note that I perform my analyses in `R`.

Comment: It is possible that none of your approaches is correct. Methods for dealing with time series is a whole branch of statistics. In R you'll probably want to take a look at the `arima` function. You'll want to be taking a look at autocorrelation function and the partial autocorrelation function in addition to evaluating your residuals for stationarity.

Comment: @DaltonHance : Yes, thanks. I know that ARMA/ARIMA/ARIMAX/etc. will come into play, but I guess I'm kinda hung up on the step *prior* to accounting for temporal autocorrelation. I'm just wondering how to put my time data into the model *at all*.

Comment: As long as you're data do not have gaps, or you can pad out the gaps with NAs or with imputation, you may not need to put time into your model at all. The `arima` function assumes that your data are an ordered time-series with equal intervals (e.g. for you it would be a monthly). But it may be better to create a time-series object. Take a look at the [`xts` class](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/xts/index.html), for example. There are numerous packages and tools in R for dealing with time-series data [(example)](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/timeseries.html).